# why using multiple threading to get the sum is correct?

Tags: python

my code is

```
import threading

counter = 0

def worker():
    global counter
    counter += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    for i in range(1000):
        t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    print counter
```

because I don't use lock to protect the shared resource,i.e. counter variable, I expect that the result is a number less than 1000, but the counter is always 1000, I don't know why. Does         `counter += 1` is a atomic operation in Python?

what operations in Python are atomic using GIL?

Comment: Because of the GIL I guess

Comment: Specifically, CPython does.

Comment: @Mike what operations are atomic when using GIL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't count on `x += 1` being thread-safe. Here is [an example](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm) where it does not work (see Josiah Carlson's comment):

```
import threading
x = 0
def foo():
    global x
    for i in xrange(1000000):
        x += 1
threads = [threading.Thread(target=foo), threading.Thread(target=foo)]
for t in threads:
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print(x)
```

---

If you disassemble `foo`:

```
In [80]: import dis

In [81]: dis.dis(foo)
  4           0 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 33)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  5          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             25 INPLACE_ADD         
             26 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (x)
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
```

You see that there is a `LOAD_GLOBAL` to retrieve the value of `x`, there is an `INPLACE_ADD`, and then a `STORE_GLOBAL`.

If both threads `LOAD_GLOBAL` in succession, then they might both load the *same* value of `x`. Then they both increment to the same number, and store the same number. So the work of one thread overwrites the work of the other. This is not thread-safe.

As you can see, the final value of `x` would be 2000000 if the program were thread-safe, but instead you almost always get a number less than 2000000.

---

If you add a lock, you get the "expected" answer:

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
x = 0
def foo():
    global x
    for i in xrange(1000000):
        with lock:
            x += 1
threads = [threading.Thread(target=foo), threading.Thread(target=foo)]
for t in threads:
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print(x)
```

yields

```
2000000
```

---

I think the reason why the code you posted does not exhibit a problem:

```
for i in range(1000):
    t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

is because your `worker`s complete so darn quickly compared to the time it takes to spawn a new thread that in practice there is no competition between threads. In Josiah Carlson's example above, each thread spends a significant amount of time in `foo` which increases the chance of thread collision.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to disassemble the instructions to make sure they actually were single byte-code calls in the interpreter. I've deleted the misleading comments.

Comment: To add to your speculation at the end about why this problem isn't showing up: The interpreter has a certain number of bytecode operations that it performs before relinquishing the GIL, which off the top of my head is about 100.  So the worker threads are always going to finish well within this limit, and thus appear to be atomic.